# Count consecutive occurrence's for column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to count consecutive occurrence's for Products column. Result should be as shown in "Total counts" column. I tried using groupby with cumsum but my logic could not work

```
+----------+--------------+
| Products | Total counts |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 2        | 1            |
+----------+--------------+
| 3        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 3        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 3        | 3            |
+----------+--------------+
| 4        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
| 4        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `transform` and count,

```
df['Total counts'] = df.groupby('Products').transform('count')
```

Output:

```
   Products  Total counts
0         1             3
1         1             3
2         1             3
3         2             1
4         3             3
5         3             3
6         3             3
7         4             2
8         4             2
```

---

Consective Products, that repeat later in dataframe:

```
grp = (df['Products'] != df['Products'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Total counts'] = df.groupby(grp)['Products'].transform('count')
```

Output:

```
   Products  Total counts
0         1             3
1         1             3
2         1             3
3         2             1
4         3             3
5         3             3
6         3             3
7         4             2
8         4             2
```

Comment: Maybe include an option where the "consecutive" aspect is at play?

Comment: @HenryEcker Point taken.... Thanks.

Comment: I knew you'd just missed it. =)